# Какие глаголы корректнее использовать со словом ряды?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистическая-сочетаемость

Какие глаголы корректнее использовать со словом ряды? 
Увелививать/расширять/пополнять и др.

Answer (score 3):

Это синонимы,  но в каждом случае лучше подходит один из глаголов, что определяется его семантикой:

**Увеличивались** ряды, но тускнел облик и расслаивались монолитные ряды старого добровольчества (А. И. Деникин).

Оказалось, что мигранты в последние годы активно **пополняют** ряды потребителей многих видов услуг.

Сейчас этой книге по справедливости  быть в ходу, тем более что ряды издателей необыкновенно **расширились**.

РАСШИРИТЬСЯ: Увеличиться в числе, в объёме, стать более крупным, более мощным. Сеть курортов расширилась.

ПОПОЛНИТЬСЯ: Сделаться более полным, увеличиться, прибавив кого-, что-л. к уже имеющемуся. Касса пополнилась. Бригада пополнилась молодыми рабочими.

Answer (score 1):

Всё зависит от контекста.

Увеличивать можно размер рядов, расширять (делать шире) можно, пополнять ряды можно чем-то. Какой контекст?

Answer (score 0):

Если речь не о геометрических, а о корпоративных рядах, то в количественном отношении их можно *пополнять* или *расширять*, в позитивном качественном отношении ряды (сотрудников или служащих) можно укреплять, сплачивать, консолидировать, оздоровлять (подвергать "чистке"); в функциональном отношении ряды можно координировать (в процессе решения совместной задачи), направлять (на её решение),  и пр.

В других конкретных смыслах ряды грамматически возможно выстраивать, располагать (один за другим), удлинять, укорачивать, прореживать, разбивать на части, занимать, высаживать, поливать, опрыскивать, сносить, поджигать (ряды смежных домов), вытаптывать и делать ещё многое из того, что возможно с предметами, расположенными рядами.